# Get Exact Answer from IBM Watson Discovery

Tags: watson, watson-discovery, nlp-question-answering

I use IBM Watson Discovery with my own document collection. When I enter a query that is "When was Stephen Hawking born?", Discovery returns related passages and one of them is "Stephen Hawking was born on 8th January 1942". The point I want to learn is that could I return just 8th January 1942 from this passage by "DATE" entitiy type?

Comment: You need to copy and paste your `code` and the `return`. Try to paste just about what you are trying and we can try to help you, your answer needs to have the programming language that you are using also

Answer (score 0):

> The point I want to learn is that could I return just 8th January 1942 from this passage by "DATE" entitiy type?

The best way to do this is probably to chunk the documents and annotate the chunks at ingestion time.  Then search the chunked documents instead of using the passage retrieval feature.  Passage retrieval does not currently identify entities within passages.

Another option is to try adjusting the `passages.characters` field.  The disadvantage with this approach is that the text will probably not be truncated around the date, or at least not consistently.

Another option is to try post processing the returned passages to extract / annotate the date entities from the results.